# Pretty urls is not working on the server yii2

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2, yii-extensions, yii-url-manager

I used the urlManager config to get a pretty urls like that :

```
   'urlManager' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'showScriptName' => false,
                'enableStrictParsing' => false,
                'rules' => [
                    'login/' => 'site/login',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>/',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>/',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                ],
            ],
```

it's working on my localhost but not on the server. the .htaccess file contents :

```
# Increase cookie security
<IfModule php5_module>
  php_value session.cookie_httponly true
</IfModule>

# Settings to hide index.php and ensure pretty urls
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Did you activate the "rewrite_module" on apache ?

Comment: yes , but it's working on the localhost server and not working on the online server , what could be the reason for this ?

Answer (score 1):

An important thing to be done:

`Recent Apache versions (from 2.3.9) have "AllowOverride None" by default and versions before had "AllowOverride All" (see allowoverride).`

So the code can work on localhost but give 404 on server because of different apache versions.

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/51470-pretty-urls-and-htaccess

Comment: so, what is the right option  "AllowOverride All" or "AllowOverride None" and if i change this on my localhost how could it affect the online server ?

Answer (score 1):

Enable Pretty URL in YII2 Advance template.

First make a .htaccess file at root of your project directory, Like if your project directory name is "Yii-Advance" then make a File Yii-Advance/.htaccess and putt following code there.

**Step 1**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
RewriteRule ^admin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php


 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

**Step 2**

Make a new file named "Request.php" and put it under "common/components/" with this code.

```
     <?php

    namespace common\components;
class Request extends \yii\web\Request {
    public $web;
    public $adminUrl;

    public function getBaseUrl(){
        return str_replace($this->web, "", parent::getBaseUrl()) . $this->adminUrl;
    }


/*
    If you don't have this function, the admin site will 404 if you leave off
    the trailing slash.

    E.g.:

    Wouldn't work:
    site.com/admin

    Would work:
    site.com/admin/

    Using this function, both will work.
*/
public function resolvePathInfo(){
    if($this->getUrl() === $this->adminUrl){
        return "";
        }else{
            return parent::resolvePathInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3**

Now install Put these lines under frontend/config/main.php

```
  'request'=>[
    'class' => 'common\components\Request',
    'web'=> '/frontend/web'
],
```

**Step 4**

Put these lines under backend/config/main.php

```
  'request'=>[
    'class' => 'common\components\Request',
    'web'=> '/backend/web',
    'adminUrl' => '/admin'
],
```

**Step 6**

Enable Pretty URLs in Frontend/config/main.php and in backend/config/main.php in this way, in my case i have two controllers "Site, User"

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<alias:index|login|logout|contact|about|signup|request-password-reset|reset-password>' => 'site/<alias>',
            '<alias:index|create|confirm|confirmation|update|delete>' => 'user/<alias>',
        ],
    ],
```

**That's it**

Now when you access your yii2 advance template application then you will see url in this way

Before these steps URL is: http://localhost/Yii-Advance/frontend/web/site/login

After these steps URL is : http://localhost/Yii-Advance/login